# Is it possible to ask for a Linux server when creating a Web App on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've created an ASP.NET Core application on my Ubuntu machine. When I host it on an Azure Web App I noticed it was running on a Windows Server. Is it possible to host it on a Linux server instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Azure Web App is using Windows Server as operating system. You can always get our own computing machine, with Linux (Ubuntu or something else) and deploy whatever you need on it.
See here for details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/

Answer (score 4):

You now can, without the need of a virtual machine or Docker image.

Create a web app with App Service on Linux.

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-linux-how-to-create-a-web-app/

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible at the moment, ran at the same problem last week while migrating some stuff from AWS. In order to keep running my apps in a Unix environment, I had to resort to Azure Container Service, but it in turn forced me to (learn and) run DC/OS.

Comment: Someone already posted the same answer two hours prior. And... as the other answer states, you *can* run Linux workloads. No issues at all. You just can't run Linux workloads as a Web App (PaaS).

Comment: Well, sorry if i wasn't explicit enough in my answer, but i was referring exclusively to the Web App service, and how i wasn't able to use that but turned to Container Service instead.